# Simple RewriteRule for first directory

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

This is pretty basic but I can't find a solution that works. I just need to redirect any URLs from an old directory to a new URL.

Example:

```
/search/whatever
```

to

```
/jobs/search
```

I don't need to map the whatever, I want all traffic to a URL that begins /search to get redirected (301).

Using this:

```
RewriteRule /search /jobs [R=301,L]
```

Works but I have a URL within /jobs that also now gets redirected:

```
/jobs/search
```

And that's wrong - it needs to match the start of the URL. So I tried this:

```
RewriteRule ^/search /jobs [R=301,L]
```

But that doesn't redirect at all, so I'm stuck.

Another example would be this:

RewriteRule /careers-at-pure /emea/contact-us/careers-at-pure [R=301,L]

This creates a loop as careers-at-pure is in the old and new URLs, but the following doesn't get matched and redirected:

RewriteRule ^/careers-at-pure /emea/contact-us/careers-at-pure [R=301,L]

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The leading slash is removed from the URI when they're being put through rewrite rules in htaccess files. You need to remove the leading slash from the regex, or at least make it optional:

```
RewriteRule ^/?search /jobs [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thanks, Jon. Unfortunately I'm still not seeing any redirection happening. It only redirects when I remove the ^ character.

Comment: @RussBack Is this because this is all happening in a subdirectory?

Comment: the requirement is for a new site. The old URLs need to be redirected to new ones. Thinking about it more, the new location isn't a subdirectory, it's a URL that gets rewritten to /index.php?jobs. To keep URLs clean I'd like to redirect /search to /jobs though. Does that make sense?